# What is the best way to handle blog post images for mobile web?

Tags: performance, image, optimization, mobile

I am creating a mobile version of a rather large and photo heavy site. I am concerned about load time for some of the blog posts which have quite a few images.

What is the best approach for dealing with blog post images for a mobile website? In many cases, the images are needed for reference within the post and creating new smaller versions of the images are out of the question.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at Matt Wilcox's adaptive images - http://adaptive-images.com/ - it's not perfect though

These articles are also worth a read - http://www.cloudfour.com/responsive-imgs/ and http://www.cloudfour.com/responsive-imgs-part-2/